# Is there a way to highlight the text in code block with bold/italic?

Tags: support

Often, there are scenarios to highlight the changes made to the user's code when answering.

But using Bold Italic in code block makes it appear like below

```
***Codeblock***
```

Is there a different way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to do it that looks "nice." What I typically do is just add comments to the code:

```
// *** Next line is where the error is *** //
Integr x = 5;
```

That usually gets the point across just fine.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. Is there a possibility of considering this as a feature request?

Comment: @Swetha Presumably, you could ask [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) tagged as "feature-request", and someone at StackExchange will take a look and provide an answer.